# Modify enum.IntFlag __repr__

Tags: python, enums

I have written a small utility that decodes log output consisting of bit-flags. I use enums when decoding those bit-flags.

```
python --version
Python 3.8.6
```

For brevity reasons, I only want to  print the enumeration member name. I've distilled my problem down to this short snippet:

```
from enum import IntFlag
class Foo(IntFlag):
    A = 0x01
    B = 0x02
    C = 0x04
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
    __repr__ = __str__
```

It works fine if I show them individually or if I print them as part of a list. But I can't print an or-expression. I want to display the flags on the form `A|B|C`.

```
>>> Foo.A
A
>>> Foo.B
B
>>> [Foo.A, Foo.B]
[A, C]
>>> Foo.A | Foo.B
TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type NoneType)
```

**Update**: I was looking at the wrong version of the source code. The `IntFlag::__repr__` for the 3.8.6 tag does contain code that does print each member https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.6/Lib/enum.py#L761

<strike>I tried reading CPythons [Lib/enum.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/enum.py) but couldn't figure out how thedefault IntFlag (without my overriden `__repr__`) prints the output on the form `Foo.A|Foo.B`.~~</strike>

I can see that [`IntFlag.__or__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/enum.py#L1272) returns a new object by calling `__class__` (I don't really know what `__class__` does). And [`Enum.__repr__`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/enum.py#L960) just prints a single class name and enumeration name.

**How** do I write a `__repr__` function and a `__str__` function which returns a string representation of the enumeration member names that are currently set?

Comment: You're reading the wrong version of the source code - the `__repr__` behavior you're looking for got removed in the master branch recently. (Always look at the code for the version you're actually using!)

Comment: `enum` has way too much weird magic in it.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Ah, you're right: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.8.6/Lib/enum.py#L761 has a loop that prints the enumeration members. And I do agree with you that there's a lot going on inside enum.py.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from enum import Flag, _power_of_two

class BetterFlag(Flag):
    def __repr__(self):
        if self.value == 0:
            return "%s(0)" % self.__class__.__name__
        return '|'.join(
                m.name
                for m in self.__class__
                if m.value & self.value and _power_of_two(m.value)
                )
    __str__ = __repr__
```

Python 3.10 and earlier do this by testing if the `name` attribute is `None`, and if so then looping over the contents.  The looping was flawed for more exotic enums, and has been redone in 3.11.

Note:  The above is forwards and backwards compatible.  Have your `Flag`s inherit from `BetterFlag`.

Comment: The __class__ member makes it possible to write a StrMixin with repr and str impl. Useful for me who want to modify both IntEnum and IntFlag.

Comment: Is _power_of_two really a public api? It starts with an underscore. Aren't those functions private by convention?

Comment: It is not a public API, but it does the job.  You could 1) copy it into your own code; 2) add a test so you know when it breaks; 3) remove the `BetterFlag` work-around when it's no longer necessary.  I would suggest either (1) or (2)(3).

Answer (score 1):

I came up with this solution

```
class Foo(IntFlag):
    A = 0x01
    B = 0x02
    C = 0x04
    def __repr__(self):
        return '|'.join(val.name for val in Foo if self.value & val)
```

And a demonstration in the repl:

```
>>> Foo.A | Foo.C | Foo.B
A|B|C
>>> Foo.A
A
```

Comment: Your solution will work fine as long as your `Flag`s are simple.  It will fail if you have named combinations in the `Flag` class definition, such as `AB = 0x03`, `BC = 0x06`.